# Как пользоваться библиотекой?

Tags: c#, excel

C# знаю очень плохо. Однако пытаюсь на нем делать не сложные задачи. Написал я программу которая формирует csv файл. Однако мне не csv нужен, в xlsx файл. Нашел, что можно использовать библиотеку http://epplus.codeplex.com/
Типа в ней это есть. Однако не нашел примеров подобной конвертации и документации.

Не могли бы подсказать, как узнать, что умеет эта библиотека. Как вы узнаете ее функции и их вызовы
Второе - как сделать нужную мне задачу. Конвертировать csv в xlsx?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [Open XML SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk).

Пример генерации .xlsx-файлов с помощью Open XML SDK [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chrisrae/creating-a-simple-xlsx-from-scratch-using-the-open-xml-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

Насчет того, как мы узнаем функции и их вызовы:

Сначала пытаемся воспользоваться документацией. Зачастую ее нет по нужному функционалу или вообще нет. (Однако, если на первый взгляд ее не видно, то нужно сначала посмотреть по внимательнее, потому что она то на стартовой странице, то в отдельном табе, то на каком-нибудь другом сайте.)

Дальше топаем к исходникам. В исходниках кроме самих исходников часто бывают примеры. Еще бывают юнит-тесты, которые тоже работают как мини-примеры.

Когда и это не помогает, тогда уже можно смотреть сами исходники. Это не значит, что придется в них разбираться: человеко-ориентированная структура папок, названия файлов, классов, методов и их параметров помогают понять, где лежит нужный функционал и как подразумевалось использовать его.

Кроме всего этого, с помощью Object Explorer в VS можно посмотреть, что есть вообще в используемой библиотеке. Это зачастую спасает от лишних кликов, требующихся для загрузки и открытия исходников.